# Retrieving list of video information for an auto-generated YouTube playlist using v3 API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

```
//  This is a first attempt at using YouTube's v3 API. It doesn't require authentication.
getAutoGeneratedPlaylistData: function() {

    gapi.client.setApiKey('{API_KEY}');
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {

        var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
            part: 'contentDetails',
            maxResults: 50,
            playlistId: 'ALYL4kY05133rTMhTulSaXKj_Y6el9q0JH',
            fields: 'items/contentDetails'
        });

        request.execute(function (response) {
            console.log("Response:", response);
        });

    });

}
```

This code takes the playlistId of an auto-generated YouTube playlist and retrieves the first 50 items from it.

The provided response's contentDetails contains each video's ID.

It seems like if I want to retrieve all of the video information for an auto-generated playlist I will need to issue 2N requests to youtube? N requests to retrieve all of the video IDs from the playlist in sets of no more than 50. Once I have all of the video IDs... then I need to ask YouTube for video information for all of the videos. I can get data for 50 videos in one request... so that's another N requests to YouTube to retrieve all of the videos?

This seems like a poor design decision. Previously, using v2 API, if I was retrieving all of the information for a playlist I could be sent all the necessary information for the videos in the initial request.

Is this no longer possible using the V3 API? Am I supposed to incur O(2N) network costs...? Really?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but isnt it just 2n requests? 2 per video?

Comment: Ahh yeah, you're right. Rusty apparently, I suppose it's not so bad.. just shocked I can't get the video information at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What additional video information are you after? If you need publication date, title, description, thumbnails, position in the playlist, etc., then that is in the snippet of the playlistItem, not the contentDetails. In fact, the snippet also contains a resourceId, which in turn has the videoId, so you could ignore the contentDetails anyway and just do:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 50,
    playlistId: 'ALYL4kY05133rTMhTulSaXKj_Y6el9q0JH'
});
```

(possibly using a fields parameter to only select those parts of the snippet you're after).

If you need video information in addition to the fields in the snippet, then you're correct that you'll have to make another set of calls (in batches of 50). This is actually a very good design decision. Nearly all use cases for playlist item requests never need more than the info in the snippet, so they can cut down significantly on sending a whole bunch of data to a whole bunch of apps that just ignore it. It does require that, in those use cases that need extra data, extra calls have to be made, but the efficiency of the entire system gets better (a very utilitarian engineering choice).

Comment: Fair enough. I require the video's duration, author, title and id. It looks like I will need to incur additional requests.

Comment: I've been in that boat as well!